# bad performance on OpenGL (qt port to android)

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt-necessitas

necessitas port Qt to Android

I have developed clone of classical game Break The Wall. Until now I have used QPainter with QPixmaps for drawing. Recently I have switched  the drawing to OpenGL.
Performances have dropped for about 5 times although I have been using native painting.
So please , if somebody knows about any kind of similar problem let me now.

Specs:
All game(around 3000 code_line) is written on smartphone HTC Desire with C4droid IDE (from google play). Desire is rooted and have mildwild cyanogenmode 5.0.
I haven't tested it on emulator or anything else so the problem is maybe related to mobilePhone.

I'd appreciate any experiance with necessitas OpenGL(no matter developed on pc or phone ).

One last thing , I have fps counter and it counts very good results in game_loop but drawing is awefully twitching.

Thanks

Comment: Two possibilities come to mind. One would be are you clearing your buffers? The other is perhaps you could cap your fps.

Comment: I ported some applications originally for Linux Embedded to necessitas and OpenGL performance is good for me.

Comment: Luca Carlon ; thanks for info

Comment: babno thanks for advice but in this case i allready did what you propose.